# Why does Pandas Series.isin work for strings but not numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

Simple example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
         columns=['x', 'y', 'z'],
         data=np.array([
             ['a', 1, 'foo'],
             ['b', 2, 'bar'],
             ['c', 3, 'biz'],
             ['d', 99, 'baz'] ]))
>>> df
   x   y    z
0  a   1  foo
1  b   2  bar
2  c   3  biz
3  d  99  baz

>>> df[df.z.isin(['foo', 'biz'])]
   x  y    z
0  a  1  foo
2  c  3  biz
```

That works as expected!

However, now I try to use `y`:

```
>>> df[df.y.isin([1,3])]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [x, y, z]
Index: []
```

What just happened?

I would have expected the same two rows to be output as in the above `.z.isin(...)` example.

Comment: `df.y = df.y.astype(int)` and then it works. It's of `object` type currently. I'm not quite sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the source of the problem. It's actually the call to `np.array`.

```
np.array([['a', 1, 'foo'],
          ['b', 2, 'bar'],
          ['c', 3, 'biz'],
          ['d', 99, 'baz']])
```

This actually coerces the integers to strings:

```
array([['a', '1', 'foo'],
       ['b', '2', 'bar'],
       ['c', '3', 'biz'],
       ['d', '99', 'baz']], dtype='<U3')
```

Notice the second column is all strings, because of type coercion. OTOH, if you initialise the array with an explicit `dtype=object`, the individual types are preserved:

```
data = np.array([['a', 1, 'foo'],
                 ['b', 2, 'bar'],
                 ['c', 3, 'biz'],
                 ['d', 99, 'baz']], dtype=object)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y', 'z'], data=data)
df.y.isin([1,3])

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: y, dtype: bool
```

Or, better still, pass a heterogenous list of lists (without conversion to array).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a', 1, 'foo'],
                        ['b', 2, 'bar'],
                        ['c', 3, 'biz'],
                        ['d', 99, 'baz']], 
                  columns=list('xyz'))
df.y.isin([1,3])

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: y, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `df.y` it is of type `object`, if you convert it to an int you will get the behavior you expect

```
In [8]: df.y
Out[8]: 
0     1
1     2
2     3
3    99
Name: y, dtype: object
```

Comment: It is a good workaround, thanks. Do you know *why* it is that way, perchance?  Documented anywhere?

Comment: You never articulated the type of your numpy array so it defaults to object, given your constructor for example it would be perfectly legitimate to have your "y" column to have the following data: `[1, 2, 3, "some_str"]`